# How can I check a 0-confirmation Bitcoin transaction without having the private key in my wallet?

Tags: php, transactions, confirmation, bitcoin

I am programming a site that accepts Bitcoin payments, but I do not want to hold any private keys on the server. I am using the so-called "lazy API" method where I create private keys and addresses ahead of time off-line, and then get customers to send to them, and I want to be notified when the transaction happens, as fast as possible, with 0 confirmations.

I can't figure out how to do this programmatically, unless I add the private key to bitcoind's wallet, which I don't want to do for security reasons. I'd prefer to do it in PHP, but I'll settle for whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check your own bitcoin client for a transaction to a specific address. You can use https://blockchain.info/api.

Also, since version .10.0 the bitcoin client supports watch only addresses which allows you to add the public key without the private key and observe transactions this way.

Answer (score 0):

On the Lazy API page, it suggests using blockexplorer.com to check for confirmations.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Lazy_API#Solution_for_receiving_bitcoins

#4 under Solution for Receiving Bitcoins:

> Check blockexplorer to see if they sent the right amount (i.e.
>   http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/19hMEAaRMbEhfSkeU4GT8mgSuyR4t4M6TH/1)
>   - the /1 is the number of confirmations you require